# C++ and C# libraries and Classes

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Can I use C++ library and Classes to building a program in C# language?
If I can , how ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`P/Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to call unmanaged code from managed code. Here's an example of calling the unmanaged `puts` function:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    public static extern int puts([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string m);
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    internal static extern int _flushall();

    public static void Main() 
    {
        puts("Hello World!");
        _flushall();
    }
}
```

The idea here consist in declaring a managed wrapper that will match the signature of the unmanaged method you want to invoke. Notice how the method is marked with the `extern` keyword and decorated with the `DllImport` attribute indicating where it is implemented.

Comment: that what i want thank you Darin Dimitrov

Answer (score 1):

Most certainly you can!

If you have a pre-existing library The mechanism that @Darin is referring to can be done automatically.  With [www.swig.org](http://www.swig.org)